# Ottawa Sitecore User Group - August 23, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** 5:30pm eastern
- **Date/Time (UTC):** 9:30pm UTC
- **Location:** Avanade/Accenture's Ottawa Office, 45 O'Connor Street 6th Floor, Ottawa, ON
- **Links to event details:** https://www.meetup.com/Ottawa-Sitecore-User-Group/events/252596378/
- **Who to contact for information:** Kamruz Jaman and Eduardo Moraes
- **A description of the event**:

> Come join us for the first Ottawa SUG meetup of 2018!
>
> Topics to be covered:
>
> **Sitecore and NightwatchJS: Our Experience Creating
>   Integration Tests in Sitecore** - by Hugo Santos, Coveo For Sitecore
>   Developer @Coveo
>
> **Integrating Azure B2C and Azure Blob Storage with Sitecore** - By
>   Eduardo Moraes and Vickram Ramehsbabu, Avanade
>
> **Creating web forms with the new Sitecore 9 Forms** - By Kamruz Jaman,
>   Sitecore MVP

Comment: Community Promotion is active